# p:barcode images do not scan

Tags: primefaces, barcode4j

I am using primefaces p:barcode tag and while the barcodes are being generated, my scanner has difficulty scanning them.

Its pretty simple:

```
<p:column>
    <f:facet name="header">
    <h:outputText value="Bottle Name" title="Bottle Name" />
    </f:facet>
    <p:barcode value="#{bottle.BottleLotId}" type="code128" title="BottleId=#{bottle.BottleId}" format="png" />
</p:column>
```

I can't seem to find any way to control the resolution of the generated png.  Has anyone used this tag or suggest some other way of generating barcodes?

Comment: and the problem is ?!? does it not retrieve the date taht you proviede or it's something else ?!?

Comment: Scanning from where? Printer? Screen? Looked at the PF docs about the height and width? It 'just' works for our cheap-ass scanners